# Getting hydration errors when trying to pass data from server component to client component in next js 13

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, supabase, hydration

Im trying to pass in a user to the Header component from my root layout. Header is a client component. Everything works well, but i get a few hydration errors.

`Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server. Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <a>.`

`Unhandled Runtime Error Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.`

Here's layout.ts in the route dir

```
const getUser = async () => {
    const supabase = createServerComponentClient({ cookies });
    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.getSession();
    handleError(error, "Error fetching user");
    return data?.session?.user ?? null;
};

export default async function RootLayout({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
    const user = await getUser();

    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body className="bg-slate-50">
                <Header user={user} />
                {children}
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

Here's part of Header.tsx

```
export default function Header({ user }: { user: User | null }) {
    return (
        <header className="h-16 bg-emerald-500 flex items-center p-4 justify-between">
            <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
                <div className="flex items-center">
                    <Link className="text-4xl" href="/">
                        <span className="text-emerald-200">Track</span>
                        <span className="text-white">Rack</span>
                    </Link>
                </div>
                {user && (
                    <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
                        <HeaderLink
                            href={`/${user?.user_metadata?.username}/projects`}
                        >
                            Projects
                        </HeaderLink>
                        <HeaderLink
                            href={`/${user?.user_metadata?.username}/collaborations`}
                        >
                            Collaborations
                        </HeaderLink>
                        <HeaderLink href="/community">Community</HeaderLink>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
            {user ? (
                <RightSideHeaderData user={user} />
            ) : (
                <div className="flex gap-2">
                    <Link
                        className="bg-black bg-opacity-5 hover:bg-emerald-600 px-2 py-1 rounded-md text-white"
                        href="/login"
                    >
                        Login
                    </Link>

                    <Link
                        href="/sign-up"
                        className="bg-black px-2 py-1 rounded-md text-white"
                    >
                        Create an account
                    </Link>
                </div>
            )}
        </header>
    );
}
```

When I removed all hooks from the Header component, the errors went away. So i'm guessing you can't pass in async props from server to client components? But i [read online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76384104/how-do-i-pass-data-from-server-component-to-client-component-in-next-js-13-app-r) you can.

If anyone can tell me what i'm doing wrong, please let me know. I'm new to using NextJs and supabase. Thank you!